# Using a variable for the table name in an INSERT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to specify table name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877624/is-there-a-way-to-specify-table-name-as-a-string)

The following script will be executed without error:

```
DECLARE @SourceDB sysname, @SourceTable sysname, 
        @UserID NVARCHAR(500), @DMLType CHAR(1), @SourceIdent uniqueidentifier, @ChangedData XML,
        @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- xml datatype and its capabilities rock
SELECT  @SourceDB = T.c.query('/AuditMsg/SourceDb').value('.[1]', 'sysname'),
        @SourceTable = T.c.query('/AuditMsg/SourceTable').value('.[1]', 'sysname'),
        @SourceIdent = T.c.query('/AuditMsg/SourceIdent').value('.[1]', 'uniqueidentifier'),
        @UserID = T.c.query('/AuditMsg/UserId').value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
        @DMLType = T.c.query('/AuditMsg/DMLType').value('.[1]', 'CHAR(1)'),
        @ChangedData = T.c.query('*')
FROM    @msgBody.nodes('/AuditMsg/ChangedData') T(c)

INSERT INTO dbo.AVE_Stamm(SourceDB, SourceIdent, UserID, DMLType, ChangedData)
SELECT @SourceDB, @SourceIdent, @UserID, @DMLType, @ChangedData
```

But when I change the `INSERT` statement to

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO @SourceTable (SELECT @SourceDB, @SourceIdent, @DMLType, @ChangedData, @UserID)';
EXEC (@sql);
```

it isn't working anymore. Can please someone help me, what's wrong here?

I use this script in a stored procedure of a SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you will either need to insert the parameter values into the string using concatenation:

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @SourceTable + ' SELECT ....';
EXEC (@sql);
```

or use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO '+@SourceTable+' (VALUES '''+@SourceDB+''', '''+
    @SourceIdent+''', '''+@DMLType+''', '''+@ChangedData+''', '''+@UserID+''')';
```

The variables are no longer in scope once you pass the string into an EXECUTE.  You need to build the string you pass in by concatenating the values.  Also, VALUES is more appropriate than a SELECT for this type of INSERT.

If your XML might have quote characters, you'll need to do the following instead...

```
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO '+@SourceTable+' (VALUES '''+@SourceDB+''', '''+
    @SourceIdent+''', '''+@DMLType+''', '''+REPLACE(@ChangedData,'''','''''')+''', '''+@UserID+''')';
```

Comment: Can you please provide some context/reasoning behind this answer for the OPs benefit.

Comment: Thank you. But `@SourceIdent` is of type uniqueidentifier and `@ChangedData` is of Type xml - what does I have to do to use this variables in your solution (there seems problems with the string concatination)

Comment: Those types are usually converted implicitly to strings in TSQL.  What error are you getting?  It could be a quote character embedded in the XML.  I've added code to address that in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't look complete to me, but you should use [sp_ExecuteSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and defining the parameters for the statement. See MSDN for more information on sp_ExecuteSQL.