# Single insert query for all table with placeholders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL, I have been working on SAP ABAP, I have searched over every where but am not able to understand the answer for my requirement.

In ABAP we can use a single `INSERT` query for all different tables with the help of placeholders.

Ex:

```
Insert into (Place-holder) values WA.
```

We will be passing the table name to the placeholder and the values to WA.

Is there a possible way for that in SQL?

Like, if I define my insert query in a global class, and I will pass on the values and the table name for `INSERT` operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to specify table name as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6877624/427192)

Comment: No, not really - and it really doesn't make a lot of sense, either, since I typically don't have 50 tables that all have the same columns - so I really cannot see any benefit of having a "generic" `INSERT` statement - that would be only good for a single table (or two - at most)

Comment: Actually @DanPichelman,My requirement is also not to insert in the same table,This single query should satisfy all my TABLES,which are having different columns.Thats why i asked.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [`EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) function in Microsoft SQL Server. It takes SQL as a string, where you can substitute the table name in the SQL query string.

However, use this with due care. It might make your application vulnerable to attacks and it is important you're careful about the transaction context implications of `EXECUTE`ing SQL as a string. I too basically support [marc_s's statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653889/single-insert-query-for-all-table-with-placeholders/16653988?noredirect=1#comment23955876_16653889) in his comment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply meid...Just now i tried EXECUTE function,and it seems to suit my requirement.But am not aware of the the attacks,Could you please tell me? @matthias meid

Comment: @AskarImran I'm thinking mainly of SQL injection. Classic approaches like parameterized queries don't work here. You need to make sure *you* are always in control of what tables are read or written, not a user who operates your program. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to create WA (structure) dynamically with RTTC (Run Time Type Creation),
here you can find an example:
 https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Add+a+column+to+an+internal+table+dynamically 
Kris

Comment: These concepts are new to me and I can't find anywhere what this WA is, what it represents. If a table returns WA, what does that mean?
Thank you in advance!